# Why is this std::sort comparison failing?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std

I have a vector of vectors of unsigned ints. Each element of the parent vector is a vector of three unsigned ints. I primarily want to sort the parent vector in descending order of the first element of the child vectors, but I also want to order any child vectors that have the same first element in *ascending* order of the third element. I initially did this with the following code:

```
sort(league_vector.begin(), league_vector.end());
reverse(league_vector.begin(), league_vector.end());
sort(league_vector.begin(), league_vector.end(),
   [](const std::vector<unsigned int>& a, const std::vector<unsigned int>& b) {return a[0] == b[0] && a[2] < b[2];});
```

So just sorting, then reversing, the whole thing, which will order by the first element. Then a custom sort using a lambda function which should only return true if the third element is smaller *and* the first element is equal.

This seems to work fine when I have a relatively small number of elements in the parent vector (around 50 or less), but when I have more than this the final ordering is coming out pretty jumbled with no obvious pattern at all.

I've replaced this with a single custom sort:

```
sort(league_vector.begin(), league_vector.end(),
   [](const std::vector<unsigned int>& a, const std::vector<unsigned int>& b)
   {return ((a[0] > b[0]) || (a[0] == b[0] && a[2] < b[2]));});
```

So this returns true either when the first element is larger, or when the third element is smaller AND the first element is the same. This seems to work fine so I am just using that, but I can't work out what's wrong with the first approach. Particularly as the first approach seems to work some of the time, and the second comparison is just an extension of the first anyway.

Comment: Does `a[0] == b[0] && a[2] < b[2]` satisfy strict weak ordering? I would think it doesn't. Also your second comparater is also weird, you check > on [0] but < on [2]

Comment: @O'Neil Actually, that's not the problem. Asymmetry is only broken when `a < b && a > b`. If `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`, that just means the two elements are equal. This comparison doesn't respect transitivity of incomparability though.

Comment: The documentation explain it although it does not goes into details for one that have not yet learn about that: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: @Borgleader To the second part of your question, that is deliberate. I'm essentially ranking the number of "wins", with the higher numbers being at the top of the list. But when there is a tie for that number, I want them to be ranked by which was achieved first, so in that case it's the lower number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `std::sort` is not a stable sort, which means it doesn't preserve the order of equivalent elements. If you want a stable sort, use `std::stable_sort`. Also, your custom comparison function makes no sense. Let's analyze how it behaves:

If `a[0]` is equal to `b[0]`, your function returns the result of comparing `a[2]` and `b[2]`. However, if `a[0]` is not equal to `b[0]`, your function always returns false. Since equivalence is defined as `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`, according to your comparison function, any two vectors with different first elements are equal.

This function also isn't a valid comparison function because it does not satisfy a strict weak ordering. Any two vectors with different first elements are equal but two vectors with the same first element are not necessarily equal. This means that if `a = {1, 2, 3}`, `b = {2, 3, 4}`, and `c = {1, 3, 4}`, `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c`.

Comment: Thanks. I had to read through that a few times, but I think I've got my head around it. I think the root problem is/was me not really understanding how the sort algorithm actually works.

So if I've followed you correctly, my second comparison function should actually be okay as vectors with different first elements will now never be equal. They will only ever be equal if both the first and third elements are the same, which is correct (although this will never happen in this particular case as the third elements are all unique values). That should also satisfy the strict weak ordering too.

Comment: The only confusion is how often the first method actually seemed to work when the vector was only a few tens of elements. I guess I just got lucky that the order of equivalent elements was being preserved from the first two sorting operations.

Comment: @MyDarts Yes, your second function is correct. Think about it like this: if the first elements aren't equal, we just return the result of comparing those elements. If the first elements are equal, we break the tie by returning the result of comparing the third elements. You could also write it like this: `a[0] != b[0] ? a[0] < b[0] : a[2] < b[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why did your first attempt fail?  Let's take a concrete example and focus on this comparison, and try to explain why this is invalid by doing a simple test.

Here are the two league vectors as an example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> league_vector = {{1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4,5}, {4,5,6,7}};
```

Now give this to `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(league_vector.begin(), league_vector.end(),
          [](const std::vector<unsigned int>& a, 
          const std::vector<unsigned int>& b) {return a[0] == b[0] && a[2] < b[2];});
```

Concentrate on this:

`a[0] == b[0]`

So let's say `std::sort` gives your comparison the first two vectors in `league_vector` in this order

`a={1,2,3,4} b={2,3,4,5}`

Your comparison function will return `false` since `a[0] != b[0]`.

Then what if the compiler does a switch up, and gives you this right afterwards, just to see if your function is not ambiguous:

`a={2,3,4,5} b={1,2,3,4}`

In other words, a simple switch of the values. You again return `false` since `a[0] != b[0]`.

How could that make sense, where you are saying on the first test `a` should come after `b` and at the second test with just switched values, `a` should come after `b`?

The sort algorithm justifiably becomes confused, and puts values in some unorthodox order.

Note that the Visual Studio compiler does this test I described, where the comparison function is given `a` and `b`, the return value is checked, and then `b` and `a` and the return value checked.  If there is an inconsistency as pointed out, the debug runtime asserts with an "invalid comparison" (or similar) condition.

Comment: Actually, there's nothing wrong with the comparison function returning false in both directions with the same elements. That just means the elements are equal. There is a problem when `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c`, where equality is defined using the OP's comparison operator.